# Add to database dynamically using dbcontext

Tags: c#, database, methods, dbcontext

I am trying to add different objects to my database using dbcontext, this is my(not working) code:

```
    public void insert(object data)
    {
        var db = new TestDbEntities();
        db.(typeof(data)).add(data);
    }
```

So I know I could so some overloading of the method insert with each kind table in the db, but I am hoping I could kinda do it like above?

Comment: So you want based on the type of the `data` object to add the object to the appropriate `DbSet` (table)?

Comment: yea exactly without using switches/ ifs or overloading if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DbContext.Set Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set(System.Type)) for that like this

```
public void insert(object data)
{
    var db = new TestDbEntities();
    db.Set(data.GetType()).Add(data);
}
```